# C Program - Bottom View of a Binary Tree

Tags: c

I am a Java Developer but i am given a task to write code for Bottom View of a Binary Tree in C. I have to complete `void bottomView(btree* root)` function but it's giving SEGMENTATION FAULT on calling `void initializeQueue(queue* q)`. Actually I know how to do this in Java but I am new to C so having troubles fixing this. I got to know this is some memory allocation issue. The bodies of the `struct queue` & `void initializeQueue(queue* q)` are as below and i am not allowed to change them. Kindly help :)

```
typedef struct queue{
  btree* node[67];
  int front;
  int rear;
}queue;
void initializeQueue(queue* q){
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<67;i++) q->node[i] = NULL;
  q->front=-1;
  q->rear=-1;
}
void bottomView(btree* root){
  int view[67];
  queue* q;
  //initializeQueue(q);  Calling this gives SEGMENTATION FAULT
}
```

Comment: I see no initialization of the printer queue. The pointer queue needs to be allocated in memory.

Comment: Hii @Emreİriş! How can i initialize the pointer? I tried the {} method but i guess it's not working.

Comment: queue *q = malloc(sizeof(queue)); is used for memory allocation. Also you can define as queue q and give address of q to function like initializeQueue(&q);

Comment: Thank you @Emreİriş! I got it now. I will look in malloc/calloc more in C. Thank you for your help :) Have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
queue* q;
```

in an uninizialized pointer that doesn't point anywhere sensible. Dereferencing it with `*q` or `q->...` will lead to undefined behaviour, usually a crash.

Create an uninitialized queue object on the stack, then create a pointer to it with the address-of operator `&` and pass that pointer to the initialization function:

```
queue q;       // uninitialized stack object

initializeQueue(&q);
```

An alternative is to create the queue on the heap with `malloc`, but you have to `free` it explicitly later:

```
queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));    // uninitialized heap object
                                  // TODO: test for NULL

initializeQueue(q);

// use the queue q

free(q)
```

You can combine allocation and initialization:

```
queue *createQueue(void) 
{
    queue *q = malloc(sizeof(*q));

    initializeQueue(q);

    return q;
}
```